# R Eval issue with function return

Tags: r, function, eval

Can anyone tell me why the use of `eval(parse(text=xxxx))` fails when it is used to select between one of several data frames to output as the return from a function

e.g. I have three data frames generated within a function;

aaa.df, bbb.df, ccc.df

and a 'mode' parameter e.g. aaa / bbb / ccc (which denotes in this case which data frame to return from the function)

the following two-liner works fine

```
eval(parse(text=paste("output.df<-",mode,".df", sep="")))
return(output.df)
```

however when I try to condense these two lines purely for a little added brevity, removing the intermediate assignment to output.df, it doesn't output the data frame

e.g.

```
eval(parse(text=paste("return(",mode,".df)", sep="")))
```

It will not be a big deal for me to continue with the first approach until I end up with a very large data frame to return, at which point I assume there could be some performance / memory hit.

Comment: It's hard to say because you didn't provide enough so we could re-create your problem. But did you try putting parenthesis around your whole expression? `(eval(parse(text=paste("return(",mode,".df)", sep=""))))`

Comment: Didn't try that tbh. I would have thought (although now you're suggesting it I am less confident) that wrapping an entire expression in brackets like that would have absolutely zero effect on code execution. But there's maybe a facet of R syntax that I missed here...

Comment: There are surely much better ways to choose which data.frame to return from a function. `eval(parse())` is usually a bad idea in R code. Even a simple `get()` would probably be better here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `return`, it’s completely unnecessary and honestly not at all meaningful.

```
eval(parse(text=paste0(mode,".df")))
```

Better yet, don’t use `eval` here — it’s probably the worst possible solution. Instead, put your data into a structured table or list format. Or, worst case, use `get`:

```
get(paste0(mode, '.df'))
```

But really, just put the data into a named list.

Comment: Removing return doesn't seem to work inside the eval structure. However return(get... does work. So thanks for that. Upvoting. Cheers...

Comment: And +1 for paste0 also...I can stop using sep="" - also appreciated

Comment: @Pascoe Yes, removing `return` does nothing *since `return` itself does nothing here*. Like I said, it’s just useless. Incidentally, it’s *also* unnecessary when used together with `get`, unless you want to exit the function early.